# Django - get item with index in template

Tags: html, django

While redirecting to index.html, I pass the topics variable in the argument:

```
def index(request):
    args={
        'user': request.user,
        'topics': Topic.objects.all(),
    }

    return render(request, 'index/index.html', args)
```

Now in the template, I want to get the second topic from the list. Tried doing like

```
{{topics.get(1)}}
```

or

```
{{topics}}.get(1)
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You want `{{ topics.1 }}`.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you! well, I didn't find the same question. Sorry for that